# Allow only one collapse div in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have some data in the ng repeat, and inside that I have some data under each divs which is collapsed.

No when I click on the main div, I want only one div to collapse in at a time.

Eg: if I click **abc**, **asdasd** should be displayed.. Then if I click **abc1**, **asdasd1** should be displayed but **NOT asdasd**

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(s) {
   s.people = [
{name:"Sten", age:"49"}
,{name:"John", age:"39"}
,{name:"Hanne", age:"37"}
,{name:"Jens", age:"37"}
,{name:"Brian", age:"24"}
,{name:"Johnny", age:"24"}
,{name:"Peter", age:"49"}
]
s.obj = [
              {
                "name":'abc',
                "text":'asdasd'
              },
              {
                "name":'abc1',
                "text":'asdasd1'
              }
              ]
}])
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">

<div ng-repeat="ob in obj">
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#abc-{{ob.name}}"> {{ob.name}}</button>
    <div id="abc-{{ob.name}}" class="collapse">{{ob.text}}</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**data-parent** is not working for me, or may be I am not using it properly.

**Please Check the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0xenc5md/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pure Angular approach rather than using JQuery for this.

Add a new property `show` to the each object and use `ng-if` to show/hide its corresponding text using a method in controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="ob in obj">
   <button class="btn" ng-click=" showThis(ob)"> {{ob.name}}</button>
   <div ng-if="ob.show">{{ob.text}}</div>
</div>
```

controller method

```
s.showThis = function(obj) {
   //Hides all
   angular.forEach(s.obj, function(ob) {
      if(ob.name != obj.name) {
           ob.show = false;
      }
    });

   //Toggles current object show/hide
   obj.show = !obj.show;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79mjwnf8/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, just that I am not getting the animation. But thats okay . Thanks again !